# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name'

Tags: c#

I'm a c# begginer and my code generates the CS0236 error, I've created a class with a
`LvlData` struct that contains a couple of variables and a `readLvl` function that takes the directory of a text file and returns a `LvlData` based on that.

However, when trying to use it (`public LvlData CurrentLevelData = readLvl("../Level/Def/lvl.txt");`) it throws an [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name'.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236) error.

Here's the LevelManager class:

```
 class LevelManager
    {
        public LevelManager()
        {
           
        }

        public struct LvlData
        {
            public LvlData(int width, int height, string tiledata,string colisiondata,string flag = "0")
            {
                Width = width;
                Height = height;
                TileData = tiledata;
                CollisionData = colisiondata;
                Flag = flag; //Deafult 0 Beacuse we sometimes don't have it
            }

            public int Width { get; }
            public int Height { get; }
            public string TileData { get; }
            public string CollisionData { get; }
            public string Flag { get; }
        }
        public LvlData readLvl(string dir)
        {
            int w, h;
            string tiled, colliiond, f;

            // Read the file 
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dir);

            w = int.Parse(lines[0]);
            h = int.Parse(lines[1]);

            tiled = lines[2];
            colliiond = lines[3];
            f = lines[4];

            LvlData deta = new LvlData(w, h, tiled, colliiond, f);

            return deta;
        }

        public LvlData CurrentLevelData = readLvl("../Level/Def/lvl.txt");

        
}
```

Comment: Try making your `readLvl` method static. However, I would instead call the function in the constructor. Complex method calls in a field initializer are confusing.

Comment: Read the error message and think about it. It's saying that the only way to have a field initializer is to have something that's known before the  constructor runs. That's because field initialization runs right before the constructor runs right before the constructor runs (and, it can't really run code beyond assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to move a method call to the constructor

```
 class LevelManager
    {
      public LvlData CurrentLevelData {get; set;}

       public LevelManager()
        {
           CurrentLevelData = readLvl("../Level/Def/lvl.txt");
        }
```

or make the method and property static, but it doesn't make much sense

```
public static LvlData CurrentLevelData {get; set; } = readLvl("../Level/Def/lvl.txt");

public static LvlData readLvl(string dir)
{
.....
}
```